# read css file from HTML throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below code to read and append to a div tag.(I have a requirement to implement this.)

```
var totalCss= "\n";
    var requiredSheets = ['test.css']; 
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var s = 0; s <= classes.length; s++) {
        var cssRules = document.styleSheets[s].cssRules ||
                document.styleSheets[s].rules || []; 
        for (var c = 0; c < cssRules.length; c++) {
            totalCss+= (cssRules[c].cssText + '\n');
        }
    }
```

Test.css is in the same folder of HTML.

My test.css have the below properties.(this is just sample)

```
.test triangle {

    stroke: #000;
    stroke-opacity: .75;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.test square {
    stroke-opacity: .75;
}

.test circle {
    stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.test .line {
    fill: none; 

}
```

When I run the snippet I'm getting

> No rules defined error

. If the styles are embedded in the same html file, the properties  are able to fetch by the code. But external files referenced in the html is not recognizing by the code.What may the cause?

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sx68T/83/)

> In this alert returns null.

Edit:

To my surprise the same code is working fine in Mozilla but showing cssrules null in chrome.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces issue.

Comment: Could you please let me know what more information you want to reproduce this?

Comment: Inner loop doesn't make sense. You already have the rules  in `classes`

Comment: Innerloop is for the rules and outer for multiple css files. Please see the fiddle I have added Nvd3 as sample external css.

Comment: The jsfiddle given alerts with the css property values in chrome. Which browser you are using?

Comment: @jaganathan Please check now.

Comment: Please see the fiddle. Im not getting alert. http://jsfiddle.net/sx68T/86/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple stylesheets with a document. So you have to loop all the stylesheets.

Below is the working example

## Update 1

Added ajax to get the external css linked with the page

```js
var style = "\n";
for (var s = 0; s < document.styleSheets.length; s++) {
  var cssRules = document.styleSheets[s].cssRules ||
    document.styleSheets[s].rules || []; // IE support
  for (var c = 0; c < cssRules.length; c++) {
    style += (cssRules[c].cssText + '\n');
  }
}
console.log(style);

//Request for each external css
$("link").each(function() {
  if (this.href) {
    $.get(this.href, function(css) {
      console.log(css);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
#car,
.car {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 11px;
  width: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the posted code and my code? and please note if i add the styles in the html its working fine. I want to read it from an external css file. Please refer my fiddle.

Comment: In your code, your are always taking styleSheet[0]. In this case, the 0th styleSheet might not have the cssRules.

Comment: Hit "Run code snippet" button given in my answer. It should print the css defined in the answer

Comment: Your code is working because you define the styles in the same page. I want to refer an external css. That's my question

Comment: Is your external style sheet included into the page?

Comment: nv.d3.css has been referred in the page.

Comment: Getting error  {
  "message": "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 29,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125342/discussion-between-jaganathan-bantheswaran-and-user1357872).